# Calabash Android Soft Buttons and Hard Buttons detection

Tags: android, ruby, testing, cucumber, calabash

I'm creating tests in Calabash for both Android and iOS.

Right now the app will use the 'menu' button on devices with physical buttons. And will present a menu option when there are no physical buttons.

Currently, the calabash tests fail on the device with the physical buttons (as they were designed with the soft button).

Is there a way to detect the model of phone (or the presence of hard buttons) with calabash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally I had found and Identified the 'menu' button by querying the screen.

```
touch("com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowMenuButton marked:'More options'") // terrible way to do this.
```

However, this (obviously) didn't work for older devices where the menu button isn't displayed in favor of a physical button.

The better way is to use the "press_menu" action:

```
performAction('press_menu')
```

This is also a predefined step:

```
Then /^I press the menu key$/
```

Defined in:

```
calabash-android/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/steps/navigation_steps.rb
```

by:

```
Then /^I press the menu key$/ do
  performAction('press_menu')
end
```